# Given the president supports a "clean" CR, when can the US federal government reopen?

Tags: united-states, government-shutdown

The president has announced that he supports a continuing resolution temporarily reopening the US federal government (which is currently partially shut down). Since the opposing party has already supported a temporary reopening, this seems promising. The problem is that it's Friday afternoon and the actual CR doesn't seem to exist in either the House or the Senate yet, and the president can't actually introduce legislation himself... (I don't think the House was even in session today, per the calendar.)

What does the timeline look like, assuming that whichever chamber passes it first passes a "clean" bill? Is either chamber likely to meet this weekend to try and pass something? If all parties do agree on the CR, what is the soonest that it goes into effect? When would federal employees need to return to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the House and the Senate have passed two bills that when combined reopen the quarter of the government that was shutdown.

They are:

- [H.J.Res.28](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-joint-resolution/28) - Further Additional Continuing Appropriations Act, 2019
- [H.J.Res.31](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/house-joint-resolution/31) - Making further continuing appropriations for the Department of Homeland Security for fiscal year 2019, and for other purposes.

Per the [@SenateCloakroom](https://mobile.twitter.com/SenateCloakroom/status/1088913875934752770)‘s tweet:

> Adopted by Voice Vote: H.J. Res. 28, as amended (Short term CR through February 15th) and H.J. Res. 31, as amended (sends DHS Appropriations to Conference and authorizes the appointment of Conferees).

The final text of the House joint resolutions and the roll call votes are still not available as of now.

The government will reopen as soon as President Trump signs both bills into law. According to media reports, he’s [expected to sign them tonight](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/pelosi-schumer-speak-after-trump-announces-deal-to-reopen-government-2019-1-25-live-updates/).

#### Update

President Trump has signed H.J.Res.28 into law, per a [press release from the White House](https://www.documentcloud.org/documents/5695730-READ-White-House-releases-statement-announced.html#document/p1).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Senate just passed it, https://www.c-span.org/video/?c4776554/senate-unanimously-approves-deal-open-government so I imagine it'll happen at some point tonight.